# Some more unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[Trick to breaking down air routes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/trick-to-breaking-down-air-routes)

[Can Serbian dinars be exchanged in the Republic of Macedonia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/can-serbian-dinars-be-exchanged-in-the-republic-of-macedonia)

[What supporting evidence is required for a Moroccan travel visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/supporting-evidence-required-for-moroccan-travel-visa)

[Pass in the Alps that can be crossed by mountain bike?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/pass-in-the-alps-that-can-be-crossed-by-mountain-bike)

[Can I take multiple cars into Mexico from the U.S.?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/can-i-take-multiple-cars-into-mexico-from-the-u-s)

[Annapurna Tilicho Lake without camping?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/annapurna-tilicho-lake-without-camping)

[How to travel with a (small) child in Vietnam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/travel-with-a-child-in-vietnam)

[What is the simplest visa requirement for a New Zealander to work in Argentina?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/what-is-the-simplest-visa-requirement-for-a-new-zealander-to-work-in-argentina)

[How can I Travel and Teach English in Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/travel-and-teaching-english-in-thailand)

[Which countries, if any, offer on-arrival work visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/on-arrival-work-visas)

[Are there any travel experiences in Australia that offer aboriginal (or Torres Strait) “cultural immersion”?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/are-there-any-travel-experiences-in-australia-that-offer-aboriginal-or-torres-st)

[Forgot baggage at Dubai. How to get it to Los Angeles?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/forgot-baggage-at-dubai-how-to-get-it-to-los-angeles)

Quite a few, 5 of which have bounties on them.  All have votes for them. But no answers? Any suggestions for how we can get more of these answered - several of them are quite simply.  Perhaps you'd like to have a crack at a couple of them? :D

I actually tweeted out 3 the other day, and twitter reset my password claiming a rogue site had taken over my account, haha :)